# "It's better not" vs. "It'd be better not"

Tags: grammar

Which of these are correct? If both, which sounds more normal?

1) If it’s not to give my all, it’s better not to have started.

2) If it’s not to give my all, it’d be better not to have started.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The "actual" English equivalent is *If a job's worth doing, it's worth doing well* (or *...doing properly / right / etc.*).

Comment: @Jake Are you referring to something you have started already, or something you are considering starting?

Comment: @Naomi started already, in this example.